# High chart only showing one point - mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am trying to populate a High Chart line graph from my database.

My Appointment Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Left IOP")]
public int IOPLeft { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Patient")]
public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
```

I have created the following controller:

```
public ActionResult IOPLeftChart(Guid? id) //
{
    var dataLeft = (from d in db.Appointments
                    where d.PatientId == id
                    select new 
                    {
                        Date = d.Date,
                        IOPLeft = d.IOPLeft,
                    }).ToList();

    var xSeries = dataLeft.Select(a => a.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).ToArray();
    var ySeries = dataLeft.Select(a => new object[]{a.IOPLeft}).ToArray();


    // instantiate an object  of the high charts type
    var chart = new Highcharts("chart")
        // define the type of chart
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
        //overall title of the chart
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Left IOP" })
        //small label below the main title
            .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "LeftIOP" })
        // load the x values
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = xSeries })
        // set the y title
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "IOP" } })
                .SetTooltip(new Tooltip
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    Formatter = @"function() { return '<b>'+this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+this.x+': '+this.y;}"
                })
                    .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                    {
                        Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                        {
                            DataLabels = new PlotOptionsLineDataLabels
                            {
                                Enabled = true
                            },
                            EnableMouseTracking = false
                        }
                    })
        //load y values
    .SetSeries(new[]
    {
        new Series {Name = "Patient", 
        Data = new Data(new object[] {ySeries})},

    });
```

My view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "IOPLeftChart";
}

<h2>IOPLeftChart</h2>

@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts

<p> My Chart </p>
@(Model)
```

However when I run the application it only displays a line when it should display a line with 3 points. As Below:

[image]
I cant see where Im going wrong, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code on the view. If you open up your web browser development tools can you see any errors? Debug the application and does what you are returning to the view look correctly?

Comment: @JamieRees I've added the code from the view. There are no errors in the development tools

Comment: so what's the output of "ySeries = dataLeft.Select(a => new object[]{a.IOPLeft}).ToArray();" ? Does that return the data points you expect, in the proper format?

Comment: @jlbriggs Ive added a screen grab. It should show 3 dates along the x axis and then 3 points on the line graph, however it is only showing one line.

Comment: Right. But what is the output of 'ySeries'? You have a function to build the series data and assign to the variable ySeries - what is the content of that variable?

Comment: On another note, since your are plotting time series data, it would make more sense to build an array of [x,y] pairs (date/value) as the data array, and skip the categories.